# How to display recommended items on product details with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Iam displaying the product details when we click on product name.The product details iam getting from the json file.i want to show the similar items in my product details page.how can i achieve it?

Comment: You should have a recommendation system setup in which you are pulling related products based on tags, titles or any related fields.

Comment: can you give me clear idea on what is meant by reccomendation setup?

Comment: I mean a recommendation feature.

Comment: It would be really helpful if You can share some code.

Answer (score 0):

Make a service that return the similar items based on the similarity criteria(i.e key-vale you are using in your JSON which are similar)

Answer (score 0):

In a website I sorted festivals with same months or regions, You can extract them out and show them in your similar list.

[click here to see implementation, click on "All Packages"](http://festola.com/festivals/list)

This was very basic implementation but you might get a basic idea :)